# Chaining Linux terminal commands

Tags: pipe, espeak

I have a function that has my EV3 speak

```
speak(){ espeak -a 200 -s 130 -v la --stdout "$@" | aplay; }
```

it works by simply

```
speak "Say this"
```

I want it to say the contents of a file, so I have this

```
printf '%b\n' "$(cat joyPhrase)"
```

How do get the output from the printf into the quotes for speak?

Comment: Are there control characters in `joyPhrase` (I assume so because of the `%b` you're using)? Can you share a sample `joyPhrase` file?

Comment: output of printf command
```Give the person to your right a high five evif hgih a tfel ruoy ot nosrep eht eviG
I don't know what %b is for, taking it out made no difference

Answer (score 1):

`espeak` supports using [`--stdin`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/espeak) to read from a pipe, so one option would be to change your function call to use that instead of parameters, and pipe the printf output into your function:

```
speak(){ espeak -a 200 -s 130 -v la --stdout --stdin | aplay; }
printf '%b\n' "$(cat joyPhrase)" | speak
```

Or you can pass the output of your other command to `speak`'s parameters, like this (although that's less likely to work if there are control characters):

```
speak $(printf '%b\n' "$(cat joyPhrase)")
```

Comment: echo $(printf...joyPhrase)") shows the current output by the speech is only two syllables and nonsensical.
adjust the speak () function like you said and then 
printf '%b\n' "$(cat joyPhrase)" | speak produce the current length but completely garbled response.

Comment: why don't you just `speak <joyPhrase` or `cat joyPhrase | speak` ?

Comment: Thanks for the backticks tip. printf command outputs correctly. I tried flipping the text in joyPhrase in case it read backwards, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the double quotes

```
printf '%b\n' "\"$(cat joyPhrase)\""
```

On my machine

```
$ echo this is a file >> testfile
$ printf '%b\n' "\"$(cat testfile)\""
"this is a file"
```

Instead of using cat, you can use the redirect:

```
$ printf '%b\n' "\"$(< testfile)\""
"this is a file"
```